# Questions due to the asker not understanding references

Tags: support

There are lots of questions asked each day which are due to the asker not knowing about the basic concept of references, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26407846/python-printed-variable-mismatch) being a [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29) example. I've answered a couple of them myself.

Since references is a concept rather than some API, and the question rarely mentions that concept, I really doubt this will help others coming from Google.

Are such questions useful? How should one deal with such questions?

Comment: Those kind of questions will forever keep coming, always looking different.  Just keep a reference question handy with an answer that addresses the core problem so you can quickly close them as a duplicate.  If you don't have such a Q+A available then write one.

Comment: There used to be a halfway decent closing code for "didn't read the documentation", but they took it away in the last closing code massacre.

Comment: I would consider also tagging these with [reference-vs-value] or something like that.

Answer (score 18):

For better or worse, the information that we collect on Stack Overflow is mostly conceptual information hidden behind numerous code troubleshooting stumbles.

The way we integrate such questions is to find duplicates which we can close them against, which I see has already been done.  If a high-quality canonical/reference post that a neophyte can understand does not exist, consider creating one for this purpose.

Comment: It is incredibly hard to find duplicates for many common questions, in large part because the dupes are so common and so poor that none gets answered or upvoted to allow it to be used as a dupe.

Comment: That's a good observation.  I don't have an obvious solution, beyond someone taking the time to create a good quality, self-answered canonical/reference question (that's a good solution, actually).

Comment: @HotLicks: as an example of this sort of question/answer, see [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it), if I do say so myself.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Some SO denizens are actively opposed to creating new self-answered  canonical questions. They will downvote because it is not *their* question and answer. Even if none of the previous duplicate questions are suitable as a canonical question.

Comment: @Raedwald: I can't imagine why.  There isn't anything objectionable about a well-written canonical question/answer pair.  Nothing whatsoever.  If people are downvoting because it's not *their* question/answer, they're kinda missing the point.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - I made an attempt to create a self-answered canonical question a few days ago, and several people down-voted it almost immediately, because it was self-answered.